# Use image buttons for pagination - Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, pagination

The default pagination in drupal is great, but the text links are used

```
<<first <previous 6 7 next> last>>
```

But I need to use forward and backward *image* buttons instead of text links. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what portions of the pager you're interested in replacing with images, you may be able to use CSS background images, without having to override the theme function. However, in the default pager output, not all the links may have unique classes.

That said, if you're using Drupal's default pager, you can override the [theme_pager function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6) to add your image links.

If you're using the Views module, you may be using a different theming function. When in doubt, you should be able to use the [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to find which function or template file is outputting the part of the page you're interested in theming. Theme Developer will also tell you what suggestions you can use to override the output.